# Try Catch for PermissionError in pd.ExcelWriter to recall function after closing spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have a function that takes a DataFrame and creates a spreadsheet.

```
def createSpreadsheet(data):
    with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Similarities')
```

I use the program regularly and don't always remember to close out of the previous Output.xlsx file - when I leave it open, I get the following error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Output.xlsx'

I'm looking to add a try/catch to catch the PermissionError that either creates "Output_copy.xlsx" or, better, has a prompt to say "Close the Output spreadsheet and press enter" and then recalls the function. I tried the below but I still hit the error (I also tried having the except clause without specifying the error to no avail):

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

def createSpreadsheet(data):
    try:
        with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
            data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Similarities')
    except PermissionError:
        input("Close the spreadsheet and press enter.")
        createSpreadsheet(data)
```

Any help gladly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by wrapping the try and except around the actual call of my createSpreadsheet function in my main prgram.

```
try:
    dm.createSpreadsheet(updateSimilaritySummaryDf)
except:
    input("Close the spreadsheet and try again...")
    dm.createSpreadsheet(updateSimilaritySummaryDf)
```

Comment: The same could be achieved inside your function. You "solved" your problem by catching just any exception whatsoever. This is considered a code smell by a number of developers (it also catches keyboard interrups, you can't to Ctrl-C anymore). I think your code will be cleaner and better to understand if you catch the specific exception that causes your issue, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The exception to catch depends on the engine you use. As you did't specify an engine in `pd.ExcelWriter` the default engine will be used. In your case this is obviously `xlsxwriter`.

So you have two options: either you specify the `openpyxl` engine and catch `PermissionError` or you specify the `xlsxwriter` engine and catch `xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError` error:

```
try:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\temp\Output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='w') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Similarities')
except PermissionError:
    input("Close the spreadsheet and press enter.")
```

or

```
import xlsxwriter

try:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\temp\Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', mode='w') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Similarities')
except xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError:
    input("Close the spreadsheet and press enter.")
```

or - to be on the safe side - catch both (if you have `xlsxwriter` installed):

```
import xlsxwriter
try:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\temp\Output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Similarities')
except (xlsxwriter.exceptions.FileCreateError, PermissionError):
    input("Close the spreadsheet and press enter.")
```

Comment: I've tried all three of those options and unfortunately none of them have worked - I get the following traceback:

Comment: You forgot to show the traceback. What does it show when you do  `except Exception as e:` and inside the exception block `print(e.__class__)`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to hit the except clause when I wrap it around the "with" statement. Let me try it inside the "with" statement

Comment: then I suppose you should check your indents, I reproduced it 1:1 as shown in the answer and it works.